# division by zero in this sql query?

Tags: php, mysql

i am executing this sql query to update the database

```
$sql_select = "UPDATE `database1`.`media` SET `media` =(http://torcache.net/torrent/'" . $upload_result . "'.torrent) WHERE 'image_type'= '4' AND 'media' LIKE '"%$fname%"' ";
```

and i am getting the Warning: Division by zero??

I think it has something to do with this condition `LIKE '"%$fname%"' "`

which uses the sql LIKE %% to match any string because i have never used this condition before in my code

where would the error be coming from?

Comment: Not from this line, that's for sure

Comment: Probably should learn to quote your values in queries.

Comment: You are missing some quotes, you can see it here in the Syntax highlighting

Comment: Honest mistake. Sometimes you need another pair of eyes. +1 for asking anyway !!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The percent sign is outside the quote, making it MODULUS, or remainder from division.

```
$sql_select = "UPDATE `database1`.`media` SET `media` =(http://torcache.net/torrent/'" . $upload_result . "'.torrent) WHERE 'image_type'= '4' AND 'media' LIKE '%".$fname."%' ";
```